# Devise Return to URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In my application controller I have

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :save_location
  def save_location
    session[:user_return_to] = request.url unless request.url =~ %r{/}
  end
end
```

...which saves the location so when the user logs in, it returns to that URL. Is it possible to do the same thing when a user signs out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define Devise's built-in **after_sign_out_path_for** method on your ApplicationController, as explained on their wiki: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-redirect-path-after-destroying-a-session-i.e.-signing-out

Comment: That's great. Should I make the before_filter and save_location under private the same that Devise has their **after_sign_out_path_for**?

Comment: It's a good practice to keep controller methods that aren't actions (meaning that no URL would resolve to it) under private, so make only your method private, leave the before_filter call where it is ;)

Comment: Ah, right. I tried using `session[:user_return_to] = request.url unless request.url =~ %r{/}` for `def after_sign_out_path_for` but it returned an error. Is there an easier way to return the URL before?